# Using exclude with Django fieldsets

Tags: django, admin, fieldset

I'm trying to write a dynamic form for models that allow users with different permissions to do different things. What I would like is for the below code to function properly, so that non-superusers can't edit any of the fields in the 'Merchant' block.

```
class CategoryModelAdmin(LWModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Merchant', {'fields': ('merchant',) }),
        ('Category', { 'fields': ('name', 'parent',) }),
    )
    def get_form(self,request,obj=None, **kwargs): 
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude = []
        else:
            self.exclude = ['Merchant']
        return super(CategoryModelAdmin,self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
```

While I can achieve that effect via the code below, I'm really searching for the "right" way to do it and it feels like using exclude is the way to go, but I can't seem to get it right no matter what I try.

```
class CategoryModelAdmin(LWModelAdmin):
    declared_fieldsets = None
    admin_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('merchant',) }),
        ('Category', { 'fields': ('name', 'parent',) }),
    )
    restricted_fieldsets = (
        ('Category', { 'fields': ('name', 'parent',) }),
    )

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fieldsets = self.admin_fieldsets
        else:
            fieldsets = self.restricted_fieldsets
        return LWModelAdmin.fieldsets + fieldsets

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.declared_fieldsets = self.get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_form(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe, you shouldn't set attributes on self (`self.exclude` etc) in your custom ModelAdmin methods. Instead use kwargs of `ModelAdmin.get_form` and `InlineModelAdmin.get_formset` to get what you want.

Here's a simple example:

```
class CategoryModelAdmin(LWModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['exclude'] = ['foo', 'bar',]
        else:
            kwargs['fields'] = ['foo',]
        return super(CategoryModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It would have been better to use the exact example field s instead of `foo` and `bar`, are they considered as fields under a fieldset or they are fieldsets themselves ?

Comment: If there's a way of excluding the entire section once like `Category`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be more or less of a hack, but have you considered this?

> Create two different models, pointing to the same table.  Each model
>   can have it's own ModelAdmin class with whatever settings you want. 
>   Then use Django's permissions to make one of them invisible to
>   non-administrators.
>
> If you want to avoid duplicating code, you can derive both of your
>   classes from some common base class you create.

The advantage is that you wouldn't be doing anything outside of what's written in the documentation.  I don't think we're meant to be overwriting methods like `get_form` and `get_fieldsets`.  If they're not truly part of the published API, those methods may change or be removed on day, and you could get owned in an upgrade.

Just a thought...