# Exclude Django admin fieldsets

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Whats the best way of excluding `fieldsets`, I have been reading different posts like the one's below :

1. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783797/using-exclude-with-django-fieldsets).

but I couldn't get it working with them. I want to negelect the following fieldsets when it's not superuser :

- Cooperation Partner Settings.
- email_user (*This is an Inline not a field set*)

Below is the `admin.py` code

```
@admin.register(CooperationPartner, site=admin_site)
    class CooperationPartnerAdmin(model.Admin):
    
        
    
        inline_type = 'stacked'
        inline_reverse = [(
            'email_user',
            {'fields': [
                'salutation', 'title', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
            ]},
        )]
        reverse_delete_user = True
    
        form = CooperationPartnerAdminForm
    
        fieldsets_add = (
            (_('Personal Data'), {
                'fields': (
                    'birthday', 'private_address_street',
                    'private_address_house_n', 'private_address_extra',
                    'private_address_postcode', 'private_address_city',
                ),
            }),
            (_('Cooperation Partner Settings'), {
                'fields': (
                    'pool', 'custom_policy_type', 'custom_database_structure',
                    'custom_attachments',
                )
            }),
            (_('Company Data'), {
                'fields': (
                    'company', 'legal_form', 'business_address_street',
                    'business_address_house_n', 'business_address_extra',
                    'business_address_postcode', 'business_address_city',
                    'international_prefix', 'phone_number', 'career_position',
                    'loan_intermediary_permission', 'agreed_provision',
                    'bank_name', 'iban', 'bic', 'account_holder',
                    'sepa_direct_debit_mandate', 'status_decision_feedback',
                ),
            }),
        )
    
        fieldsets_change = (
            (None, {
                'fields': (
                    'cooperation_partner_id', 'account_state',
                ),
            }),
        ) + fieldsets_add
    
        def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
            """Overwrite get_form method."""
            self.fieldsets = self.fieldsets_change if obj else self.fieldsets_add
            return super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
```

EDIT :

This is my current implementation according to the answer @Ozahed,

but it doesn't make fields hidden, whats really missing :

```
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        """Overwrite get_form method."""
        self.fieldsets = self.fieldsets_change if obj else self.fieldsets_add
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
        if request.user.is_staff:
            list_of_fields_to_hide = ['pool', 'custom_policy_type', 'birthday']
            for field_name in list_of_fields_to_hide:
                form.base_fields[field_name].is_hidden = True
        return super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Django Form has a dictionary called `base_fields` that contains Field Classes and would be accessible after the `super().get_form` call. each field has its properties that we can control like `widget instance`. in your case, inside `get_forms` based on the request's user you might change the field's disabled or widget itself

```
from django.forms.widgets import HiddenInput

def get_form (self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    if not request.user.is_superuser: 

       for field_name in list_of_fields_to_hide:
           form.base_fields[field_name].widget = HiddenInput()
       
    return form
```

[Django Field API documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.is_hidden)

Comment: So , I shoud do this with field names, only  will this also make the fieldset anme dissappear like `Cooperation Partner Settings.` ?

Comment: I tried your approach, I have edited my question with respect to your approach, but still fields aren't hidden, what could be missing ?

Comment: use `form.fields[field_name].widget = forms.HiddenInput()` instead and tell me if it works

Comment: The Django am using doens't accept `form.fields` it's not in the `form` dir.

Comment: Even just tested `form.HiddenInput()` it's not available . Am using django version `2.2.24`

Comment: fields will be added to your form instance after super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) look here: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships)

Comment: But surprisingly `form.base_fields[field_name].disabled = True` works , it disables them.

Comment: good. thank you for telling me. I will update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235938/discussion-between-lutaaya-huzaifah-idris-and-ozahed).